# Uploading image in react app on digital ocean

Tags: reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, next.js

I am working on a project where I am uploading images from a react app.

```
        const accessToken = getCookies(null, 'token');
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', imageFile);

        const res = await fetch(
            url,
            {
                body: formData,
                headers: {
                    'authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                },
                method: 'POST'
            }
        )
        const data = await res.json()
```

This code works when tested on localhost with some warnings:

```
[31/Aug/2021 11:37:22] "POST /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/ HTTP/1.1" 202 13
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53246)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/arunkumar/aaa/bbb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/arunkumar/aaa/bbb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

but once deployed to server using `DigitalOcean`, the `POST` request becomes `OPTION`.

```
[xxx-dev] [2021-08-31 11:55:46] 10.244.39.74 - - [31/Aug/2021:11:55:46 +0000] "OPTIONS /aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://aaa-admin-dev-9aloh.ondigitalocean.app/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"
[xxx-dev] [2021-08-31 11:55:47] WARNING:root:DB:abc
```

The Api I am using is fine as checked via `postman`

I tried with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` too. I also tried hardcoding the boundaries too but it became worse and the local system also started behaving weirdly.

The header in localhost creates the 'Content-Type' on header by itself but does not do the same in DigitalOcean.
Can anyone suggest anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {decode} from 'base64-arraybuffer';

export const uploadFileToS3 = async (file) => {
  utils.startLoader();
  const BUCKET_NAME = 'XXX';
  const IAM_USER_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  const IAM_USER_SECRET = 'XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  const spacesEndpoint = new AWS.Endpoint('sfo3.digitaloceanspaces.com');
  const s3bucket = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY,
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    secretAccessKey: IAM_USER_SECRET,
  });
  const contentType = file.type;
  const contentDeposition = `inline;filename=${file.name}`;
  const fPath = file.uri;

  const base64 = await fs.readFile(fPath, 'base64');

  const arrayBuffer = decode(base64);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3bucket.createBucket(() => {
      const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: `${file.name}`,
        Body: arrayBuffer,
        ContentDisposition: contentDeposition,
        ContentType: contentType,
        ACL: 'public-read',
      };
      s3bucket.upload(params, (error, data) => {
        utils.stopLoader();
        if (error) {
          reject(getApiError(error));
        } else {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```